# Cant' find Android Support package

Tags: android

I have installed everything that is presented in the Android SDK manager, SDK and ADT are both up-to-date. How can I find the Android Support package?

SDK manager screenshot: [image: SDK manager screenshot]

Comment: Something failed to load, as you are missing 80% of the stuff that should be in the SDK Manager. Try clearing your cache (Tools > Options, then click Clear Cache), then reload (Packages > Reload). Android Support should be in your Extras portion of the tree.