# cannot find android support library

Tags: android, sdk, android-support-library

please **notice** that i searched a lot so this is not a duplicated question

searched these with no answer

[Can't find Android Support Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437183/cant-find-android-support-package)

[Cant' find Android Support package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243030/cant-find-android-support-package)

[How to add "Android Design Support Library" to Eclipse with ADT-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430633/how-to-add-android-design-support-library-to-eclipse-with-adt-plugin)

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#using-apis

i just want to be able to use
**TabLayout** as when i use it it says 
cannot resolve 'TabLayout' symbol.

and when i try to import it

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
says also  cannot resolve 'TabLayout'

also i searched for that error and it results to install the android support library which i cannot find

here is a search for that
[Android Studio cannot resolve symbol 'TabLayout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686324/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-tablayout)

so how to install that library ?!!

[Image of SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dadv.png)

here is the gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.engtomiwak"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Do you add it in gradle?

Comment: You should add your build.gradle files here.

Comment: if u mean adding compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+" this under dependencies , yes i did and still TabLayout cannot resolve

Comment: You can try rebuild the project.

Comment: i added the gradle in my edit @anti_gone

Comment: i don't think this is the solution **Joshua** as rebuilding the app would not get me the library or make me be able to use TabLayout

Comment: @MohamedAlaa Rebuild the project will make you clean Android Studio Cache and resync Gradle.

Comment: sry, didn't know that as i'm beginner in programming , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Then import:

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried that before but the problem was that I didn't sync gradle after adding the compile under dependencies, Thanks a lot